# Do OCUnit and OCMock work on the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, unit-testing, mocking

I simply could not make it work, and I am wondering if I am wasting my time, or if I am simply stupid!

Sorry I don't have the exact error I have right now. But I just want to know if it work or not!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know whether OCUnit works with iPhone, but there is an [iPhoneUnitTesting](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/iPhoneUnitTesting) framework available from Google Code.

Comment: The Google Toolbox for Mac is a great piece of software. I have found it to be a must have for iPhone development.

Answer (score 9):

Colin Barrett has a blog post about [OCMock and the iPhone](http://iamthewalr.us/blog/2008/11/10/ocmock-and-the-iphone/).

Answer (score 7):

Not so sure about OCMock, but OCUnit support is now included in iPhone 2.2 SDK.

You can download an example application from [Stanford iPhone Application Programming CS193P](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/index.php) Lecture 19.

Comment: The contents of that page was probably updated, there is no Lecture 19 to be found there now.

Answer (score 5):

Sen:te (the creator of the framework) explains how to use OCUnit with an iPhone project: http://www.sente.ch/s/?p=535&lang=en.

Answer (score 4):

I created some OCUnit tests for an iPhone app, but in order to run the tests I had to compile for Mac OS X, not iPhone OS, and switching back and forth was a pain.

The [Google framework](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/iPhoneUnitTesting) is cleaner, they can run the tests in the simulator or on the device.

Answer (score 4):

I got hung up on the same thing. I finally found the answer on [Mitch's World](http://mitchellhashimoto.com/using-ocmock-with-xcode-3-in-leopard/) then reposted the solution on [my site](http://codeforfun.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/ocmock-works-in-an-iphone-project/). The quick fix is to add the OCMock.framework folder to /Library/frameworks and reference it from there. For whatever reason XCode doesn't want to add folders external to its natural framework seach to the path. Until I find out more this is the best we can do.

-Cliff

Answer (score 4):

At the time of writing OCUnit "just works" on the iPhone. Apple are shipping templates that works out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look [here](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2009/05/testing/custom-xcode-template-for-iphone-development). You'll find a Xcode template you can use that has OCUnit and OCMock all ready setup for you.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in this project which integrats OCMock & gh-unit (based on Google toolkit)

[Unit test](http://github.com/JohannesRudolph/gh-unit)