# Automated testing for iPhone

Tags: iphone, testing, ios-simulator, automated-tests, ios-ui-automation

I know this one is going to be a long-shot, but I thought I'd try.  Does anyone know of any automated test *anything* for the iPhone simulator?  I'd love it if there was something like Selenium but for the iPhone simulator.  I don't need anything fancy like assertions, just something that can fake out taps on a screen so I can stop abusing my trackpad. :)

Is there a way to send taps or keyevents (like on android over adb) to iOS devices?

Comment: The face that this question gets so many favs but gets closed, says something about the decision.

Comment: The answers to this question have gotten very old since it was closed. Newer options include Appium and ios-driver (both of which are Selenium compatible), as well as Calabash, Frank, and Zucchini.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's an article about [automated user interface testing for the iPhone](https://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/automated-user-interface-testing-on.html) that you may find helpful.  It's a little kludgy but it probably gets the job done for certain tasks.  Note that I haven't yet tried it myself.

Answer (score 38):

iPhone OS 4.0 (just announced) includes a "UIAutomation Instrument" for test automation.

**Automated testing**
Automate the testing of your application by scripting touch events using the new UIAutomation Instrument.

From: http://developer.apple.com/technologies/iphone/whats-new.html#tools

Comment: Only drawback is that you need to use JavaScript, which is ok itself, but you have not much tools support like decent IDE (there are ones for web development, but not a single one for JS). As alternative you could try Sikuli (www.sikuli.org) which allows to automate anything. But I would go with Instruments from Apple.

Answer (score 13):

Gorilla Logic has just open sourced a true record/playback functional testing tool for the iPhone. It's called FoneMonkey and it's freely available at http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey.

Answer (score 5):

How to use UIAutomation to create iPhone UI tests:

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1646-how-to-use-uiautomation-to-create-iphone-ui-tests/

Comment: UIAutomation has limitations that hinder its use for automated testing. There's no command line interface, can't setup the test environment before hand. Its manual start stop. I have been able to get it started with Automator.

Answer (score 4):

See also

- [Test Driven Design for iPhone Native apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195820/test-driven-design-for-iphone-native-apps)
- [Do OCUnit and OCMock work on the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159280/do-ocunit-and-ocmock-work-on-the-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

http://code.google.com/p/uispec/

UISpec is a Behavior Driven Development framework for the iPhone that provides a full automated testing solution that drives the actual iPhone UI. It is modeled after the very popular RSpec for Ruby

Answer (score 4):

Square just released their testing framework

http://corner.squareup.com/2011/07/ios-integration-testing.html

Answer (score 4):

Telerik just released an automated testing tool for iOS - http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/ios-testing/ios-application-testing.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Good luck with trying to automate iOS platform with JS. By the time QA gets proficient with JS, well you wouldn't have to be QA anymore. There is plenty of us out there that are familiar with Selenium which in turns means you know Java to some extent. I have found a way to automate iOS using complete open source with Java Libraries.

I put up a video on it:
http://www.vimeo.com/21999946

I will will be putting up more in depth video shortly.

And since its Java it works perfectly with Junit, ANT, Maven in any CI environment.

Answer (score 2):

Check out UISpec http://code.google.com/p/uispec/

It's BDD testing framework that lets you "drive" the iphone simulator.

Best,

Brian

Answer (score 1):

See also http://www.froglogic.com/pg?id=NewsEvents&category=111

Regards,
Reginald

Answer (score 1):

Pick whichever Automation Tool you want from this page: http://www.mobileappstesting.com/category/mobile-application-testing/mobile-application-testing-and-automation-tools/

Eggplant :- http://www.testplant.com/products/eggplant/

Answer (score 1):

I blogged about KIF (Keep It Functional), this is the testframework from the company square and it is really good! I use it to test our iPhone app.

More information and an example how to setup the framework

http://dnlkntt.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/iphone-test-automation-using-kif-keep-it-functional/

Have Fun!

Answer (score 0):

There's also Keynote products. They have:

Test Center Enterprise Interactive (App platform, any device with website / app. Internal / external facing apps and websites, manual testing.)

Test Center Enterprise Automation (App platform, any device with website / app. WITH scripting.)

Test Center Developer (App platform, any device with website / app, manual, no scripting.)

Unknown costs involved, you have to call them. But the feature set is very impressive. They have multiple real devices for each handset and you just select which one you use. If they are in use you can book them etc. I think this is the ultimate option for testing any mobile app.