# Build, deploy and run iphone simulator from terminal

Tags: iphone, xcode, build

I'm new to mac & xcode. Please tell me the procedure for iphone .xcodeproject outside xcode IDE for below tasks:

1. Build- done using xcodebuild command
2. deploy in simulator  ?
3. Run in simulator.?

How to achieve this using ant/Applescript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: may be this will help you http://rajneesh071.blogspot.com/2013/04/launch-iphone-simulator-without-xcode.html

Comment: @Rajneesh071 ,thanks for the link, it was pretty helpful, is it possible to achieve the same without using commandline utility like waxsim

Comment: yes you can do it using finder -> cmnd+shift_g and then provide path

Comment: @Rajneesh071 , I followed the link you have provided, It was pretty useful in building and running but where I am stuck is how to run automated test case and build junit report without using xcode IDE Pls let me know anything regarding this

Comment: what is "automated test case" and "junit report" ?

Comment: @Rajneesh071 automated test case= automate unit test cases outside xcode, junit report = xml test case report. correct if its wrong.

Comment: do you have any link for this.. i wanna learn this...

Comment: this might help you,
http://longweekendmobile.com/2012/11/11/ios-application-unit-tests-from-the-command-line-xcode-4-5-update/
http://redgreenrefactor.eu/blog/xcode-running-logic-and-applicationtests-form-command-line/
https://github.com/ciryon/OCUnit2JUnit
http://baolei.tumblr.com/post/32428168156/ios-unit-test-from-command-line-ios6-xcode4-5

if you want anything specific just google.

Answer (score 2):

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517463/how-can-i-install-a-ipa-file-to-my-iphone-simulator)I know how to build and create .app file from out side Xcode i.e. with terminal. Open the terminal and go the specific folder where the project is created and use this command..

```
xcodebuild -workspace 'WORKSPACENAME.xcworkspace' -scheme 'APPNAME' -configuration "Debug" -sdk iphoneos6.0 -arch "armv7 armv7s" CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR='OUTPUT_DIRECTORY'
```

if you have static library attached to the project then

```
xcodebuild -workspace 'WORKSPACENAME.xcworkspace' -scheme 'APPNAME_LIB' -configuration "Debug-iphoneos" -sdk iphoneos6.0 -arch "armv7 armv7s" CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR='OUTPUT_DIRECTORY'
xcodebuild -workspace 'WORKSPACENAME.xcworkspace' -scheme 'APPNAME_LIB' -configuration "Debug" -sdk  iphoneos6.0  -arch "armv7 armv7s" CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR='OUTPUT_DIRECTORY'
```

also here is some useful links..

```
>  [https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html][2]
> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947317/can-i-install-an-app-to-the-simulator-without-the-source-code][3]
> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517463/how-can-i-install-a-ipa-file-to-my-iphone-simulator][4]
```

Comment: THanks for the reply,i did know xcodebuild command , but couldn't figure out how to deploy and run, let me know regarding the later