# iPhone Acceptance/Unit Testing

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, acceptance-testing

What is the quickest and easiest way to perform testing on an iPhone? I don;t mind if it is either unit or acceptance, but the software I have used so far seems rather longwinded?

The problem I have is that I have already created my code...I just want to test parts to make sure they work as expected...

I only want to test simple things such as text input validation...

Can anyone give any advice on how to go about this? What are the easiest ways? I don't need anything too in depth...

Comment: What do you mean by "acceptance"?  There is an button in the Organizer called Validate...

Comment: KIF, Frank and UIAutomation are all useful. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402389/automated-testing-for-iphone

Answer (score 0):

have you downloaded xcode from developer.apple.com and paid your $100 membership fee? if you have then you can test your application on your iphone.

Comment: Really? Acceptance tesing? Using what?