# Unit tests on a iOS device to automate a testing procedure?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am writing a simple app that would take data at certain interval from my server, and elaborate the data and spit out the results, saving them on the device.

IS there anything that I can use in Xcode to make something like Unit tests? I would like to run tests (maybe with a cron job) so Xcode can build the app, put it on the device and the tests can run automating the procedure.

I know how to compile and build on the machine and sync on the device, but then I am stuck about the next step...since I do not know how to tell the device to run certain steps (nor i know how to write them)

Is there anything that i can use that would allow me to accomplish this?

I've heard of UIAutomation but I am not sure that in fact it can do what i need (automate operations on a device, like a unit test would do); Unit tests does not run on device, so I am basically stuck doing the test by hand.

Any help is more than welcome!

Comment: this sure seems like [a duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402389/automated-testing-for-iphone)

Comment: Thanks Michael; that post is for the sim but has some info that may be used also in my case...gotta experiment. Thanks!