# IOS Automation Testing tools

Tags: java, xcode, windows, cucumber, calabash

I am new to mobile testing and i want to test the ios apps through any of the automation tools available in the market,could you please suggest me which tool is best ? and useful links to that tool for how to use that tool in a proper manner

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automated testing for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402389/automated-testing-for-iphone)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally prefer [Calabash](http://calaba.sh) which is built on Cucumber if you want to do acceptance tests. Then you can automate your builds using [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org). There are support for Cucumber in Jenkins as well, you can find it [here](https://github.com/masterthought/jenkins-cucumber-jvm-reports-plugin).

Comment: Thnaks for your valuable reply,could you please suggest me the links to go through about the tools like how to setup and prerequisties behind it ?

Comment: Here is the documents for calabash: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios and if you want to learn how to set up Jenkins, you can have a look here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/22590/beginning-automated-testing-with-xcode-part-12

Comment: Thanks Mikael                                                               
~Sindhuja

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gorrila](https://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk/legacy-products) and [TestStudio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/ios-testing.aspx).

Also [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402389/automated-testing-for-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Appium](http://appium.io/), which lets you write tests in many languages and test frameworks.