# Simulate cursor and click

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to simulate a mouse pointer and click event on any object in the view. Until now I am able to simulate a mouse pointer i.e. The mouse pointer moves by dragging it on the view. Now I want to fire tap event on the underlying object on which the simulated mouse pointer is clicked. Suppose a button. The concept is about a finger mouse.

Comment: As I have mentioned it a concept of finger mouse. Just like a desktop mouse.

Comment: rename the title. I get what you want but iOS has no mouse so the title is confusing

Comment: This is very confusing on what you want. Title, question content are all confusing. -1. Will remove -1 if question is made more understandable.

Comment: I am really sorry cannot express my aim of the question very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got you,

1) add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your mouse pointer.

2) in tapgesture handle method,

get the finger point,

```
CGPoint fingerlocation = [tap locationInView:self.view];
```

Make a fingerRect like this,

```
CGRect finderRect = CGRectMake(location.x - 5, location.y - 5, 10, 10);
```

iterate through all the uiviews in the self.view

```
  for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    CGRect frameOfTheView = view.frame;

    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(frameOfTheView, finderRect)){
        NSLog(@"clicked on view %@", view);
        return;
    }

}
```

Finally method will be like this,

```
-(void) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) tap{

    //get the tapped point
    CGPoint location = [tap locationInView:self.view];
    CGRect finderRect = CGRectMake(location.x - 5, location.y - 5, 10, 10);

    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        CGRect frameOfTheView = view.frame;

        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(frameOfTheView, finderRect)){
            NSLog(@"clicked on view %@", view);
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

That way you can detect the touched view, depending on the view you can call methods you want.

Comment: this is nice .. and to me the cleaner way as it doesn't use private API like I sugggested

Comment: Thanks will try this out and will post my feedback. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

with a bit of hacking and looking at the KIF testing framework:

https://github.com/square/KIF/blob/master/Additions/UIView-KIFAdditions.m 
here is a `UIView::tapAtPoint` method & an `_eventWithTouch` method

look at more code there .. it isn't all public documented API though so you are likely to get rejected for this :D

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to do this so you can run automated testing of an iOS app? If so, this thread is quite old but has links to relevent material.
[Stack Overflow 402389](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402389/automated-testing-for-iphone)

Comment: No I am not trying to test user interface. Just imagine iPad as your screen that is at some distance and you have a mouse wearable on your finger.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot simulate touches directly!!!!  That's why there is such thing as testing. You either do the deed( run the app, click and move ) or not.

Also..it's called touch, not click