# What are the best tools for unit testing iphone applications?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing

Wondering which tool is considered the best/standard and what the pros/cons are for the various unit testing tools that are available. The tools I'm aware of so far are:

- [Google Toolbox for Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/)
- [OCUnit](http://www.sente.ch/software/ocunit/) which seems to be the [winner for objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207/what-is-the-best-way-to-unit-test-objective-c-code), but some folks have had [trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159280/do-ocunit-and-ocmock-work-on-the-iphone-sdk) with on the iphone
- [rbiphonetest](http://github.com/drnic/rbiphonetest/tree/master) which Dr Nic comments on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195820/test-driven-design-for-iphone-native-apps/277777#277777)

Of course I'd love to learn about any I've missed.

Comment: Similar thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159280/do-ocunit-and-ocmock-work-on-the-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google toolbox for Mac(GTM) is a superset of OCUnit. It adds more assert macros, and also has a support for UI testing. OCMock is how you can incorporate mock objects into your unit testing environment.

I have just recently created a project and file template for creating static libraries that also has built-in support for unit testing. You can read about it:

http://www.codingventures.com/2009/04/xcode-templates-for-iphone-static-libraries-with-unit-testing/

And the templates are located at:

http://github.com/keremk/iphone-static-library-project-template/tree/master

The file template gives you an easy way to add a unit test class with all the necessary OCMock and GTM/OCUnit headers.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in answers to this question: [Do OCUnit and OCMock work on the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159280/do-ocunit-and-ocmock-work-on-the-iphone-sdk). Some links for short:

- [OCMock and the iPhone](http://iamthewalr.us/blog/2008/11/10/ocmock-and-the-iphone/)
- [iPhoneUnitTesting](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/iPhoneUnitTesting)
- [Stanford iPhone Application Programming CS193P](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/index.php)
- [Using OCMock with Xcode 3 in Leopard](http://mitchellhashimoto.com/using-ocmock-with-xcode-3-in-leopard/)
- [iPhone Unit Testing | Sen:te](http://www.sente.ch/s/?p=535&lang=en)